# How can I make this JavaScript function which alters input elements by IDs generic?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where shipping weight is calculated as separate fields for Lbs and Oz. I have a JavaScript function which watches these input elements to calculate the total weight in ounces into a hidden field which is then passed to the server when the form is submitted.

For those who are curious, weight is stored in the database as just ounces. The object that represents an inventory item also uses only ounces. The disparity is that only some forms which are meant to be used by humans separate the input into pounds and ounces.

Instead of the server handling these special cases, I felt that it made sense for it only receive the expected "ounces" calculation; this is why I'm processing this client-side and not server-side.

[image]

My JavaScript function needs to know the names of the elements to read to and write from. I have this hard-coded into the function:

```
const form_itemWeightLb = document.getElementById("item-weight-lb");
const form_itemWeightOz = document.getElementById("item-weight-oz");
const form_itemWeight = document.getElementById("item-weight");

function convertWeightToOunces() {
   let lb = form_itemWeightLb.value;
   let oz = form_itemWeightOz.value;
   
   // Convert lb + oz to oz
   ..
   
   form_itemWeight.value = calculatedWeight;
}

form_itemWeightLb.addEventListener("input", convertWeightToOunces);   
form_itemWeightOz.addEventListener("input", convertWeightToOunces);
```

I want to move this function into a script so that it can be reused elsewhere. But I don't want to tie them to specific element ids.

How can I decouple this function so that it can be reused?

Comment: Use classes and some kind of wrapping element that contains them. Pass the containing element (or something that identifies it) to a function that wraps the code you have, and instead of `document.getElementById` use `wrappingElement.querySelector`.

Comment: decouple that function from what? from the html elements?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is to pass the elements as parameters for the function. Then, whenever you're calling the function from whatever script, you pass the elements directly.

```
function convertWeightToOunces(form_itemWeightLb, form_itemWeightOz, form_itemWeight) {
   let lb = form_itemWeightLb.value;
   let oz = form_itemWeightOz.value;
   
   // Convert lb + oz to oz
   
   form_itemWeight.value = calculatedWeight;
   
   // Add the event listeners here, or maybe with another function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating class with constructor that will take ElementId's as input or simply in your function just pass element id's as input

```
class UnitOfMesurementConverter{
    constructor(lbElementId, ozElementId, itemWeightId){
    this.form_itemWeightLb = document.getElementById(lbElementId);
    this.form_itemWeightOz = document.getElementById(ozElementId);
    this.form_itemWeight = document.getElementById(itemWeightId);
  }
  

  function convertWeightToOunces() {
     let lb = form_itemWeightLb.value;
     let oz = form_itemWeightOz.value;

     // Convert lb + oz to oz
     ..

     form_itemWeight.value = calculatedWeight;
  }

  form_itemWeightLb.addEventListener("input", convertWeightToOunces);   
  form_itemWeightOz.addEventListener("input", convertWeightToOunces);
}

//then pretty much you can
const p = new UnitOfMesurementConverter("item-weight-lb","item-weight-oz","item-weight");
p.convertWeightToOunces();
```